# cannot download kernel for ubuntu

Tags: kernel

when I am trying to download kernerl 3.12.57.tar.xz I get this error.

> "/tmp/aYccRRf_.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.
>   Try again later, or contact the server administrator.""

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and do:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.12.57.tar.xz
```

You should be all set.